# How can one compute & render velocity from kml track in qgis?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, kml

I have a bunch of KML files recorded from activity trackers.  These record a stream of coordinate.  These lack individual timestamps, but one can assume that the samples were taken at regular intervals.  Is there a way of having qgis compute vector deltas between adjacent coordinate-pairs, so as to estimate a velocity?  Then I'd like to have the velocity value influence rendering of the shape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you have the track in the KML (polylines).
You should "explode" the polylines using Processing->Vector->Explode lines into a new layer. 
[image]
Add a new column to the new layer by the field calculator:

1. Toggle editing on the exploded layer
2. Open the attribute table of the exploded layer
3. Open field calculator dialog
4. Add an expression, divide the length by the elapsed time (I supposed 2 secs), and you get the speed in m/s.
   [image]
5. Finally you can create a thematic map on the speed column.

I used Qgis 3.2 but it should work in 2.18, too.